# Remove elements from string json array in MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-json

I have table with many columns that contains string array json of objects.

I need to remove several elements from these arrays.
I find how can I remove elements from one row, but how can I do it on multiple rows?

For one row I used json_search to find element that must be removed, but I have many rows and many elements to remove. Is there any way to do it without stored procedure (while loop)?

This is sample of data:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------
id | DATA                                                          |
-------------------------------------------------------------
1  | {"array":[{"a":"a","b":"b","c":"c"},{"b":"b","c":"c"}]}|
------------------------------------------------------------
2 | {"array":[{"b":"b","c":"c","f":"f"},{"b":"b","c":"c","d":"d"}]}|
-------------------------------------------------------------------
3 | {"array":[{"a":"a","b":"b","c":"c"},{"g":"g","ff":"ff"}]}|
4 | {"array":[{"q":"q"},{"g":"f","e":"e"}]}|
```

I need to remove only elements from each `array` that contans `a` and/or `g`

My query is:

```
UPDATE MY_TABLE
SET DATA = JSON_REMOVE(
    DATA,
    REPLACE(JSON_SEARCH(
                (SELECT DATA WHERE DATA LIKE "%a%"),
              'all',
              "%a%"
            ),
    '"',
    '')
) WHERE DATA LIKE "%a%";
```

I found the way how to update all columns, but this query removes only json field, not whole object. How can I remove whole object?

Comment: An `UPDATE` query will update all the rows that match the `WHERE` clause. So you just need to use a `WHERE` condition that matches all the rows you want to update.

Comment: I need to remove specific objects from json arrays which are strings.

Comment: I understand that. It will remove from all the rows that match the `WHERE` condition. Why do you think it will only remove from one row?

Comment: Add some sample data, the element you want to remove, and the query you're using. Then we can help you fix it to do what you want.

Comment: @Barmar added sample of data

Comment: You didn't add your query.

Comment: @Barmar added query

Answer (score 0):

Found the way.

The data was in `"$.array[5].a"` format after calling `JSON_SEARCH`. I just needed to wrap replace into another replace that will replace `'.a'` to just `''`.

Comment: You should post the modified query.

Comment: We are waiting for the modified query upto now... be kind and help others

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar answer and followed OP's answer and was able to get it to work! They just did:

```sql
UPDATE MY_TABLE
SET DATA = JSON_REMOVE(
    DATA,
    REPLACE(REPLACE(JSON_SEARCH(
                (SELECT DATA WHERE DATA LIKE "%a%"),
              'all',
              "%a%"
            ),
    '"',
    ''), '.a', '')
) WHERE DATA LIKE "%a%";
```